# Startup.sh file does not exist after installing tomcat9 with YUM

Tags: tomcat

I installed tomcat9 with the command below

```
sudo su
yum install tomcat9
```

But in the tomcat9 directory at `/usr/share/tomcat9/bin`, the `startup.sh` file is not found. There are only 3 files below:

```
$ls /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/
bootstrap.jar  catalina-tasks.xml  tomcat-juli.jar
```

I try to run tomcat9 also error:

```
/usr/sbin/tomcat9 start
Failed to start tomcat.service: Unit tomcat.service not found.
```

Tomcat version :

```
$java -cp /usr/share/tomcat9/lib/catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.71
Server built:   Apr 13 2023 00:00:00 UTC
Server number:  9.0.71.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     6.1.25-37.47.amzn2023.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    17.0.7+8-LTS-224
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

OS is Amazon Linux 2023

```
$cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2023"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="2023"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:al2023"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2023"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2023"
HOME_URL="https://aws.amazon.com/linux/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023"
SUPPORT_END="2028-03-01"
```

How do I fix it to run?

Comment: Which version of which distribution are you using?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I run command : `java -cp /usr/share/tomcat9/lib/catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo` and it show `Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.71
Server built:   Apr 13 2023 00:00:00 UTC
Server number:  9.0.71.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     6.1.25-37.47.amzn2023.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    17.0.7+8-LTS-224
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation`

Comment: In general I would expect that when in 2023 somebody packages server/daemon software for distribution in a RPM package that they also create the systemd unit file to have it managed. Then you can use `systemctl start tomcat9` or something

Comment: What **Linux** distribution are you using? And please, edit all additional information into your question instead of in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `repoquery -l tomcat9` the systemd unit name is `tomcat9`.

```
systemctl start tomcat9
```

relevant configuration files:

- /etc/tomcat9/tomcat9.conf
- /etc/sysconfig/tomcat9

There is also a second unit definition if you need multiple tomcat instances:

> To create clones of this service:
>
> 1. `systemctl enable tomcat@name.service`
> 2. create catalina.base directory structure in
>    `/var/lib/tomcats/name`

where `name` can be an arbitrary name of your choosing.